# Outdoor box or cover for exterior hole for network cables, what's this called?

Tags: wiring, ethernet

I'm looking to very cleanly run network cables through exterior walls of a home. This is easily doable if you silicone all around the cable to plug the hole fully, but then it'll be impossible to add more cables or move them, etc.

Is there such a thing as a weatherized outdoor cover / door / box that could cover a permanent hole while letting the cables out the sides, but prevent cold/bugs/etc? I suspect this is a thing, if only I knew the right name to search for.

Comment: "it'll be impossible to add more cables or move them, etc." that's why you run *at least* one extra wire. Moving them isn't a thing. You add one (plus one extra) where you want a new one. And do a coax. = TV, phone, and internet to every run you do, and then it's all one pull to each location. Use the same 8 wire for phone and then you can steal it for x2 internet or when that wire fails. Need a roll of RG6 and two boxes of CAT-5. "very cleanly" means never removing some wire that the siding behind hasn't been bleached by the sun, and no old holes with nothing in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seek is common in the telecommunications industry, cable and telephony alike. It is a demark or demarcation box. Its purpose is exactly as you describe, although often contains grounding and disconnect features. The box is mounted to the wall and when open, allows access to the hole through which the cables are pulled. Searching for a suitable image, I found an [answer I posted](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/148067/will-water-damage-a-spliced-coaxial-cable) to this SE from nearly five years ago! It's primarily for television cable, but for your purposes, you can find network patch boxes, although demark boxes are more likely for outside protections. One vendor resulting from the search is [MultiLink](https://www.gomultilink.com/categories/demarcation-enclosures) which is not an endorsement, merely a search result. The site lists many versions, one photo from the site is shown below:

[image: fiber cable demark]

This image appears to be for fiber optics and doesn't have the common pass-through hole in the back face. A wide variation can be found online and at local contractor supply houses, as well as Amazon.

Answer (score 2):

Use (electrical, not HVAC) **duct seal**. It's designed for use with electrical cables, and never hardens, so you can always take it out and then replace it when you want to.

You can put any normal weatherproof electrical junction box over the hole as well, if you like. You can install conduit going through the wall to that junction box or to an LB fitting - in both of those cases it's still normal good practice to use duct seal around the wires at the end of conduit.

Comment: Junction box suggestions might be helpful - something like a NEMA 3R type steel junction box, or a 4x4x2, 6x6x4, etc PVC junction box. Either one can be drilled with holes sized and positioned to suit the job with a hole saw or step drill.